# Atualizar todos os registros de uma tabela com base em um função no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, desempenho

Preciso migrar os registros de uma tabela denominada **wdo.tbatoedicao**, e para esta tarefa implementei a função **wdo.fn_executa_atualizacao_fts_ato_edicao** que será chamada sempre que houver uma inclusão/alteração de registro da tabela. O problema é que a tabela já teve inclusão de milhares de registros, e por isso é preciso que todos os registros da tabela sejam enviados para a função executar, e migrar a informação para o modo correto. Gostaria de executar a instrução de modo único, porém não encontrei uma maneira de realizar a migração sem que a execução do SQL ficasse muito lenta.

Existe alguma maneira de atingir todos os registros em uma única transação com o banco de dados passando pela função **wdo.fn_executa_atualizacao_fts_ato_edicao**?

Abaixo está o modo no qual implementei a função, e a trigger que a utiliza.

```
/*EXECUTA A ATUALIZACAO/DEFINICAO DA INDEXACAO DAS INFORMACOES DO TERMO DE BUSCA DO ATO DE UMA EDICAO*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wdo.fn_executa_atualizacao_fts_ato_edicao(iCodigoEdicao INTEGER, iCodigoTextoJur INTEGER)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN
                DELETE FROM wdo.tbatoedicaofts WHERE tbatoedicaofts.edccodigo = iCodigoEdicao AND tbatoedicaofts.txjcodigo = iCodigoTextoJur;
                
                INSERT
                  INTO wdo.tbatoedicaofts (edccodigo, txjcodigo, aeffts)
                           (SELECT edccodigo,
                                   tbatoedicao.txjcodigo,
                                           setweight(to_tsvector(LOWER(to_ascii(COALESCE(regexp_replace(tbcategoriatexto.tctdescricao,                              E'<[^>]+>', '',  'gi'), ''), 'WIN1250'::name))), 'A') ||
                                           setweight(to_tsvector(LOWER(to_ascii(COALESCE(regexp_replace(tbtextojuridico.txjementa,                                  E'<[^>]+>', ' ', 'gi'), ''), 'WIN1250'::name))), 'B') ||
                                           setweight(to_tsvector(LOWER(to_ascii(COALESCE(regexp_replace(tbtextojuridico.txjtexto,                                   E'<[^>]+>', ' ', 'gi'), ''), 'WIN1250'::name))), 'C') ||
                                           setweight(to_tsvector(lower(to_ascii(COALESCE(regexp_replace(tbtextojuridico.txjnumero || '/' || tbtextojuridico.txjano, E'<[^>]+>', '',  'gi'), ''), 'WIN1250'::name))), 'D') ||
                                           setweight(to_tsvector(lower(to_ascii(COALESCE(regexp_replace(tbtextojuridico.txjnumero || ' ' || tbtextojuridico.txjano, E'<[^>]+>', '',  'gi'), ''), 'WIN1250'::name))), 'D') as conteudo
                                  FROM wdo.tbatoedicao
                            INNER JOIN wlg.tbtextojuridico
                                    ON tbatoedicao.txjcodigo = tbtextojuridico.txjcodigo
                            INNER JOIN wlg.tbcategoriatexto
                                    ON tbtextojuridico.tctcodigo = tbcategoriatexto.tctcodigo
                                   AND tbtextojuridico.tcttipo   = tbcategoriatexto.tcttipo
                                 WHERE tbatoedicao.edccodigo     = iCodigoEdicao
                                   AND tbatoedicao.txjcodigo     = iCodigoTextoJur
                           );
        END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


/*VERIFICA SE A EDICAO ATUALIZADA ESTA APTA PARA A ATUALIZACAO/DEFINICAO DA INDEXACAO DAS INFORMACOES DO TERMO DE BUSCA DO ATO DE UMA EDICAO*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wdo.fn_insere_fts_ato_edicao()
RETURNS "trigger" AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN
                IF(tg_op = 'INSERT')
                THEN
                        PERFORM wdo.fn_executa_atualizacao_fts_ato_edicao(new.edccodigo, new.txjcodigo);
                END IF;
                RETURN NEW;
        END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```